# HTML form field data in a text file

Tags: html, forms, sed, field

I want to retrieve the HTML form field data in a text file on my desktop.

I am having a HTML page containing the HTML form field box.

Further, I want to run a bash script taking the text file as a input.The bash script contains the command :

```
 sed -f replacer input.txt > output.txt
```

I have to also include this `output.txt` file in another html form field.

Help me out.
Thank You.

Comment: Server side script is necessary for this case. Write a server side script with your own language like php, asp, etc. Send the content of text field to that server script, and there write code to write the data to text file. Also run your bash script using exec function(if php).

Comment: I am using PHP as a server side script.
Also the things seem a little diffcult in case of HTML form field using POST method.

Comment: what is that difficulty! Can you paste some code what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Have html like this:

```
<form id="some" name="someName" method="post" action="/ur/url/to/post">
   <input type="text" id="some1" class="someClass" value="" name="fileWrite"/>
   <iput type="submit" value="submit" class="submitClass"/>
</form>
```

Have a php script like this:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
if(isset($_POST['fileWrite']) && !empty($_POST['fileWrite'])) {
      $fileWrite = $_POST['fileWrite'];
}
if($fileWrite) {
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file"); //Make sure you have permission
    fwrite($fh, $fileWrite);
    fclose($fh);
    exec('/your/command /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
}
```

Thats it. Job is done.